# como soluciono el sqlite3.operationalerror: unable to open database file?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

```
# import the flask module
from flask import Flask, render_template
# we import the database tool
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy



# we set the class variable
app = Flask(__name__)
    
# we set the app in order to recognize the database and we give it a name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////db.market'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# we create our variable where the db is gonna be stored 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  # we pass our app variable as a parameter
app.app_context().push() 
# we create the class model
class Item(db.Model):
    # parameters after specifying the type of database
    # --> (data type(optional : length), nullable, unique)
    # the primary key parameter is only gonna be used on the id
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable = False, unique = True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable = False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length = 12), nullable = False, unique = True)
        
    description = db.Column(db.String(length = 500), nullable = False, unique = True)

# we set the route (url)
@app.route('/')   # decorator
# we set the main function
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market():

    items = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Phone', 'barcode': '893212299897', 'price': '$500'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Laptop', 'barcode': '123985473165', 'price': '$900'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Keyboard', 'barcode': '231985128446', 'price': '$150'}
    ]
    # primer parametro será nuestro archivo html
    return render_template('market.html', item_name = 'Phones', items = items)  # colocar el segundo parametro en el archivo html



    # dynamic routes
@app.route('/about/<username>')
def about_page(username):
    return f'<h1> this is the about page {username}  </h1>'
```

este es mi código. básicamente cuando corro en la terminal y escribo
from market import db
todo bien
despues escribo
db.create_all()
y me aparece el error de abajo.
ya he tratado de leer la documentacion tanto de flask como de sqlalchemy pero sigo sin comprender qué estoy haciendo mal. en los tutoriales que veo, sigo al pie de la letra y aun asi me suelta este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

literalmente he hecho lo mismo que en los tutoriales que veo y creo que solo a mi me sale este error. necesito ayuda

Comment: Si es Windows, posiblemente sea porque hay 4 '/' en vez de 3. Ver [documentación](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlite).